# Dual Graphics On Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Ok so I have a Lenovo W550s really good laptop with and i7 and Nvidia Quadro K620m right now Ubuntu is using Intel HD Graphics which is okay but the Quadro is better. When I try to install Nvidia drivers for my Quadro Ubuntu does not boot and I had to reinstall Ubuntu.
PS: I am dual booting and the graphics card works on windows and does not have this problem.

Comment: Does it display any error message when Ubuntu fails to boot?

Comment: No it does not just a black screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [drivers 352](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/95159/en-us) which support the NVIDIA Quadro K620M this way :

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Open NVIDIA X Server Settings -> **Prime Profiles** to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

If you have to adjust the card to to be used in BIOS, select NVIDIA or  switchable graphics mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this Lenovo model, but I have had similar problems a while ago with another Lenovo laptop having two graphic adapters.

For Windows, Lenovo had a special driver that was able to change the graphic adapter while working. The Intel adapter was meant for standard work and was using a lot less power which was good for battery. The NVidia used more power and provided 3D graphics and better performance.

I am pretty sure there is no such driver for Linux. I gave up since I didn't use any advanced graphics and used Intel on my laptop. It was sufficient for me.

I think you can configure the graphic adapters in BIOS. In that way you might succeed to run NVidia in Linux but you can forget fancy switching in Windows in that case.

Comment: You can run hybrid-graphics just fine on Ubuntu, you need Nvidia-prime as well as the driver, see @cl-netbox answer above and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that. I was trying to make it work before these hybrid graphics drivers were available.